# r run easyPubMed queries row wise from a data frame column

Tags: r, pubmed

I have a dataframe like below;

[image]

I would like to run row by row query in Pubmed using easyPubMed package. For each row/query should fetch list of PMIDs. This list should be retrived in another column called 'PMID'.

Comment: What is your question? You can use `sapply` to iterate over `Query`, for example: `sapply(dataframe$Query, easyPubMed::function)`

Comment: It should be helpful if you share your code attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work

```
library(easyPubMed)
library(purrr)
Query <- c('rituximab OR bevacizumab','meningitis OR headache')
Heading <- c('A','B')
x <- as.data.frame(cbind(Heading,Query),stringsAsFactors = F)
x$PMID<- ""
ids <- map(x[,"Query"],get_pubmed_ids)
for (i in 1:length(ids)) {
  x[i,"PMID"]<- paste(ids[[i]][["IdList"]],collapse = ",")
}
```

I think that "sapply" won't return expected results so, going the "map" way from "purrr" package is safer.

Comment: i can no longer ask question here as im blocked but i have similar question pertaining to tidypmc library right now i can query a single PMCID based on their manual is there a way where i can loop through ?